# Is it possible to send certain clicked hrefs to another BrowserWindow?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have certain hrefs which need to be processed in another BrowserWindow. The problem is that inside the mainWindow I am navigating inside an iframe and certain download links are not supported by iframes. Thus I want to pass those download links into another BrowserWindow, which doesn't contain an iframe.

My approch so far

```
    mainWindow.webContents.session.on('did-navigate-in-page', (event, item, webContents) => {
        var downloadLink = /downloadLink/g;
        if(downloadLink.test(webContents.url) ) {
            let downloadWindow = new BrowserWindow({ show: false  })
            downloadWindow.on('closed', () => {
                downloadWindow = null
            })
            downloadWindow.loadURL(webContents.url);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you could just save them to the localstorage from the browser:
`localStorage.setItem(keyname, value)`
them retrieve them in the new window with: 
`localStorage.getItem(keyname)`

Comment: I don't think that this is practical, since I need login inside Electron to download the files. Then I would have to login inside the browser and it would result in more work.